# Path and Extension do not work with the \setmathfont command in XeLaTeX package unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I would like to install some `.otf` fonts locally in a directory `./fonts` with my XeLaTeX source. Using the standard installation of XeLaTeX with TeXShop/TexLive works on Mac Mojave (see `essai1.tex`). Adding Path and Extension to the `\setmathfont` command of the `unicode-math` package does not work whether it is the default path (`essai2.tex`) or the local path (`essai3.tex`).

```
$ cat essai1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}[
      SizeFeatures = {
       {Size =      -6.01,  Font = MinionMath-Tiny},
       {Size =  6.01-8.41,  Font = MinionMath-Capt},
       {Size =  8.41-13.01, Font = MinionMath-Regular},
       {Size = 13.01-19.91, Font = MinionMath-Subh},
       {Size = 19.91-,      Font = MinionMath-Disp}
}]
\begin{document}
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1\relax
\fontspec{MinionMath-Regular}{\symbol{8594}}
\end{document}
$ xelatex essai1.tex > /dev/null
$ grep " ->" essai1.log
 -> /Users/.../Library/Fonts/MinionMath-Regular.otf
...
$ cat essai2.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}[
      Extension = .otf ,
      Path = /Users/.../Library/Fonts/ ,
      SizeFeatures = {
       {Size =      -6.01,  Font = MinionMath-Tiny},
       {Size =  6.01-8.41,  Font = MinionMath-Capt},
       {Size =  8.41-13.01, Font = MinionMath-Regular},
       {Size = 13.01-19.91, Font = MinionMath-Subh},
       {Size = 19.91-,      Font = MinionMath-Disp}
}]
\begin{document}
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1\relax
\fontspec{MinionMath-Regular}{\symbol{8594}}
\end{document}
$ xelatex essai2.tex > /dev/null
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[/Users/.../Library/Fonts/Minion Math.otf]/OT', contains '['
^D
$ ls /Users/.../Library/Fonts/MinionMath-*
/Users/.../Library/Fonts/MinionMath-Bold.otf        /Users/.../Library/Fonts/MinionMath-MediumSubh.otf
...
$ cat essai3.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}[
      Extension = .otf ,
      Path = ./fonts/ ,
      SizeFeatures = {
       {Size =      -6.01,  Font = MinionMath-Tiny},
       {Size =  6.01-8.41,  Font = MinionMath-Capt},
       {Size =  8.41-13.01, Font = MinionMath-Regular},
       {Size = 13.01-19.91, Font = MinionMath-Subh},
       {Size = 19.91-,      Font = MinionMath-Disp}
}]
\begin{document}
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1\relax
\fontspec{MinionMath-Regular}{\symbol{8594}}
\end{document}
$ xelatex essai3.tex > /dev/null
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[./fonts/Minion Math.otf]/OT', contains '['
^D
$ ls ./fonts/MinionMath*
./fonts/MinionMath-Capt.otf     ./fonts/MinionMath-Semibold.otf     ./fonts/MinionMath-SemiboldTiny.otf
...
```

Comment: Do you really have an `Minion Math.otf` with a space in the name?

Comment: The font name is "Minion Math" (checked with Font Book). But the .otf files like MinionMath-Capt.otf have no space. \setmathfont{MinionMath}[..] with no space yields `Package fontspec Error: The font "MinionMath" cannot be found.`

Comment: Don't confuse font names and file names. With Extension=otf you are telling fontspec to use file names.

Comment: The unicode doc says `\setmathfont{⟨font name⟩}[⟨font features⟩]`. `Minion Math` is the font name and `MinionMath` does not work.Eliminating `Extension = .otf ,` does not help.I don't see where is the confusion.

Comment: The only difference between `essai1` (that works with an implicit path) and `essai2/3` (that don't work with explicit paths) seems to be the handling of paths by `fontenc` and/or `unicode-math`

Comment: If the actual filename is `MinionMath-Regular.otf`, I think you need to specify that, or the loader will look for a nonexistent `Minion Math.otf`. That is, `\setmathfont{MinionMath-Regular}[Extension = .otf, Path = ...]`

Comment: If you want to load by the display name, don’t give `Extension=`; you might be able to supply the full filename, such as `MinionMath-Tiny.otf`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures[MinionMath-Regular]
    { Path = {./fonts/} ,
      Extension = .otf }
\defaultfontfeatures[MinionMath-Bold]
    { Path = {./fonts/} ,
      Extension = .otf }
\setmathfont{MinionMath-Regular}[%
      math-style=ISO,
      SizeFeatures = {
       {Size =      -6.01,  Font = MinionMath-Tiny, Style = MathScriptScript}, 
       {Size =  6.01-8.41,  Font = MinionMath-Capt, Style = MathScript},
       {Size =  8.41-13.01, Font = MinionMath-Regular},
       {Size = 13.01-19.91, Font = MinionMath-Subh},
       {Size = 19.91-,      Font = MinionMath-Disp}
}]
\setmathfont{MinionMath-Bold}[range={bfup->up,bfit->it}]
\begin{document}
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1\relax 
\tiny       
$\symbol{10520}$
\scriptsize
$\symbol{10520}$    
\footnotesize   
$\symbol{10520}$    
\small      
$\symbol{10520}$
\normalsize 
$\symbol{10520}$    
\large
$\symbol{10520}$
\Large
$\symbol{10520}$
\LARGE
$\symbol{10520}$
\huge
$\symbol{10520}$
\Huge
$\symbol{10520}$

\normalfont\normalsize
\fontspec{MinionMath-Regular.otf}[Path = ./fonts/]{\symbol{10520}}
\end{document}
```

which will look for fonts in the ./fonts/ directory.

[image]